# MySQL/SQL query based on the parameters set after a conditional query result - The function was written before in Python reading a CSV file

Tags: python, mysql, sql, csv, subquery

I have a table contaning this data:

```
"germination_day","2019-01-02","2019-03-02","08:00:00","18:00:00","100","0","2","0","0","0","0","0","24","54","0","1300","24","120"
"germination_night","2019-01-02","2019-03-02","18:00:00","08:00:00","0","96","0","0","0","0","0","0","25","40","0","1300","24","120"
" flowering_day","2019-03-02","2019-06-02","08:00:00","06:00:00","0","0","0","0","100","0","0","10","25","40","0","1300","24","120"
"flowering_night","2019-03-02","2019-06-02","06:00:00","08:00:00","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","24","120"
"vegetation_day ","2019-06-02","2019-09-02","08:00:00","06:00:00","0","0","0","0","100","0","0","10","25","40","0","1300","24","120"
"vegetation_night","2019-06-02","2019-09-02","06:00:00","08:00:00","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1300","24","120"
"maturation_day","2019-09-02","2019-12-31","08:00:00","09:00:00","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1300","24","120"
"maturation_night","2019-09-02","2019-12-31","09:00:00","08:00:00","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1300","24","120"
```

This is the visual layout of the table:
[image]

This table contains the parameters for the setting of a green house. Passing the current day and time I need to get the row of data that has the passed day in the range between start_date and end_data and the passed current time in the range between start_hour and end_hour.

Every phase is composed by day and night. it starts at 8am and ends at 8am of the following day.

This is the code that I've written so far. It's not completed because my skills in SQL are not that great. It's the reason why I need help:

```
SET @CurrentDate =  CURDATE();
SET @CurrentTime = NOW();


SELECT start_hour, end_hour, 

CASE
    WHEN CAST( CONCAT(@CurrentDate, ' ', end_hour) as DATETIME ) >  CAST( CONCAT(@CurrentDate, ' ', '00:00:00') as DATETIME ) AND CAST( CONCAT(@CurrentDate, ' ', end_hour) as DATETIME ) <= CAST( CONCAT(@CurrentDate, ' ', '08:00:00') as DATETIME )
    THEN CAST( CONCAT(@CurrentDate, ' ', end_hour) as DATETIME ) = CAST( CONCAT(@CurrentDate, ' ', end_hour) as DATETIME ) + INTERVAL 1 DAY

    WHEN CAST( CONCAT(@CurrentDate, ' ', start_hour) as DATETIME ) = CAST( CONCAT(@CurrentDate, ' ', end_hour) as DATETIME )
    THEN CAST( CONCAT(@CurrentDate, ' ', start_hour) as DATETIME ) - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE

    WHEN  NOW() >= CAST( CONCAT(@CurrentDate, ' ', start_hour) as DATETIME )
    THEN "Day phase"

    WHEN  NOW() < CAST( CONCAT(@CurrentDate, ' ', start_hour) as DATETIME ) OR ( NOW() >= CAST( CONCAT(@CurrentDate, ' ', start_hour) as DATETIME ) AND  NOW() < CAST( CONCAT(@CurrentDate, ' ', end_hour) as DATETIME ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    THEN "It goes to the night phase"
END AS expense_amt
FROM `RECIPE_TABLE`
WHERE CURDATE() >= start_date
AND CURDATE() < end_date
```

In the past I was using a file .CSV with Python. However, now for a better performance I need to implement the query in MySQL.

This was the working code (Probably it could be improved):

```
def getCurRow(self):
    currentTime = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
    inFile = open(self._recipe_file, 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(inFile, skipinitialspace=False)
    headers = reader.next();
    try:
        for index, row in enumerate(reader):
            row = [element.strip() for element in row]
            if(len(row)>=0):
                print("Row: "+str(row))

                sDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[1].strip(), "%d/%m/%Y")
                eDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[2].strip(), "%d/%m/%Y")


                self.sTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(currentTime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')+" "+row[3].strip(), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
                self.eTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(currentTime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')+" "+row[4].strip(), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

                #sTime and eTime will be also considered for the preparation of the solution
                self.sTime.replace(second=0)
                self.eTime.replace(second=0)



                if (eDate <= sDate):
                    print("Impossible eDate <= sDate ")
                    break

                print("eTime : "+str(self.eTime)+" cond1 : "+str(currentTime.replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0))+" "+"cond2 : "+str(currentTime.replace(hour=8,minute=0,second=0)))

                if (self.eTime > currentTime.replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0) and self.eTime <= currentTime.replace(hour=8,minute = 0,second=0)):
                    self.eTime = self.eTime + datetime.timedelta(days=1)


                if (currentTime <= eDate and currentTime >= sDate): # check data
                    if (self.sTime == self.eTime):
                        print("sTime = eTime")
                        self.sTime = self.sTime - datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

                        print ("currentTime: "+str(currentTime))
                        print ("startingDate: "+str(sDate))

                        print ("endDate: "+str(eDate))
                        print ("startingTime: "+str(self.sTime))
                        print ("endTime: "+str(self.eTime))

                    if(currentTime >=self.sTime) and (currentTime < self.eTime):
                            print("Day phase")
                            self.phaseID = index
                            self.phase = str(row[0].strip())

                            return row
                            break
                    elif (currentTime < self.sTime) or (currentTime >= self.eTime) and (currentTime < eDate - datetime.timedelta(days=1)):
                            #it consider the following line, the night phase
                            print("It goes to the night phase")
                            row = reader.next()
                            print("Night phase: "+str(row))
                            self.phaseID = index+1
                            print("phaseID: "+str(self.phaseID))
                            self.phase = str(row[0].strip())
                            self.sTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(currentTime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')+" "+row[3].strip(), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
                            self.eTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(currentTime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')+" "+row[4].strip(), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
                            self.eTime = self.eTime + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

                            return row
                            break
                    else:
                        print("Next range time")
                        continue
                else:
                    print("Next range days")
                    continue
            else:
                print("There are no rows")
        else:
            sys.exit('Error: File configuration ended')
            return None

    except csv.Error as e:
        sys.exit('File %s, line %d: %s' % (in_file, reader.line_num, e))
    except ValueError as e:
        sys.exit('Error: Configuration file not well formatted.\n%s' % e)
    finally:
        inFile.close()
```

Comment: I am unclear what your asking for here since ' I need to get the row that has the current date between the range of days( start_date and end_data) and (start_hour and end_hour)' is straightforward and I don't get what all those casts are for can you try to rephrase your question

Comment: I've adjusted my question. Thank you

Comment: It would be enormously helpful if you could prepare an SQL fiddle with your sample data and show exactly what output you expect from it. That somebody reverse-engineers your Python script to figure this question out is rather unlikely. Also it's better to remove the Python tag if you don't need Python help.

Comment: As output I need the data of the row of the table above that matches the current day and time.

Comment: The SQL table containing the data is on the top of this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to understand exactly what you need. As a starting point, could you explain why the following is not sufficient?

```
SELECT *
FROM `RECIPE_TABLE`
WHERE DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN `start_date` AND `end_date`
AND CURTIME() BETWEEN `start_hour` AND `end_hour`;
```

**UPDATE:**

Is the problem the time wrapping? If so, does the following produce the desired results?

```
SELECT *
FROM `RECIPE_TABLE`
WHERE
(`end_hour` > `start_hour` AND CURTIME() BETWEEN `start_hour` AND `end_hour` AND DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN `start_date` AND `end_date`) OR
(`start_hour` > `end_hour` AND CURTIME() BETWEEN `start_hour` AND '00:00:00' AND DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN `start_date` AND `end_date`) OR
(`start_hour` > `end_hour` AND CURTIME() BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND `end_hour` AND DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(`start_date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(`end_date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

**UPDATE 2:**

So it seems the issue is the definition of the date boundaries. As you stated in the comments that the first of the two rows returned is what you desire, the following adjustment works (I also fixed a time boundary issue):

```
SELECT * FROM `recipe` WHERE
(`end_hour` > `start_hour` AND CURTIME() BETWEEN `start_hour` AND `end_hour` AND DATE(NOW()) > `start_date` AND DATE(NOW()) <= `end_date`) OR
(`start_hour` > `end_hour` AND CURTIME() BETWEEN `start_hour` AND '23:59:59' AND DATE(NOW()) > `start_date` AND DATE(NOW()) <= `end_date`) OR
(`start_hour` > `end_hour` AND CURTIME() BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND `end_hour` AND DATE(NOW()) > DATE_ADD(`start_date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE(NOW()) <= DATE_ADD(`end_date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

Tested using the data provided in the SQL, with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `recipe` WHERE
(`end_hour` > `start_hour` AND '09:15:00' BETWEEN `start_hour` AND `end_hour` AND '2019-09-02' > `start_date` AND '2019-09-02' <= `end_date`) OR
(`start_hour` > `end_hour` AND '09:15:00' BETWEEN `start_hour` AND '23:59:59' AND '2019-09-02' > `start_date` AND '2019-09-02' <= `end_date`) OR
(`start_hour` > `end_hour` AND '09:15:00' BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND `end_hour` AND '2019-09-02' > DATE_ADD(`start_date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND '2019-09-02' <= DATE_ADD(`end_date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY));

+-----------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+----------+------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
| phase           | start_date | end_date   | start_hour | end_hour | color_0 | color_1 | color_2 | color_3 | color_4 | color_5 | color_6 | color_7 | temperature | humidity | photowhite | quantity_solution | quantity_cicles | quantity_duration |
+-----------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+----------+------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
| vegetation_day  | 2019-06-02 | 2019-09-02 | 08:00:00   | 06:00:00 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |     100 |       0 |       0 |      10 |          25 |       40 |          0 |              1300 |              24 |               120 |
+-----------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+----------+------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Consider the case where it is the 2019-02-15 and it's 9:15am. The row selected should be the first but with your query the first and the second would be selected. Instead, if the time is 6am the second one should be selected.

Comment: When you say "would" does that mean you didn't try the query to see if it would work, or do you mean "were returned"? :D In any case, I've updated the answer, does that solve the issue?

Comment: I've tried the code and it doesn't work.
I guess that some switch cases have to be added for the different cases like I did in the Python code above.

Comment: Eugene, have you tried to create a table structured and refilled with the CSV provided and test it with your SQL queries?

Comment: Take into consideration the image of the table included above, If you consider the second line, that one highlighted, the 08:00:00 of the end_hour is > of the start_hour (18:00:00) because it's on the following day.
This is the reason why, once that the correct date range has been found (start_daye/end_date), to find out which time range is the correct one (start_hour/end_hour) the current day has to be added in order to do the calculation.

Comment: That's what I thought, my update above accounts for this? I haven't tested, if you could provide table schema creation with dummy data, I can run that and get you the correct SQL query (sorry, lacking spare time atm!).

Comment: I added above copy of the DB exported as file SQL.

Comment: Many thanks Eugene for your help! I'm extremely greatfull!! Thanks to you the issue seems being solved. I will test it in different scenarios to test the robustness and I'll let you know. :D

Answer (score 0):

This is the DB exported as SQL file:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.8.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 00.00.101.08
-- Generato il: Nov 15, 2019 alle 12:25
-- Versione del server: 5.6.44-86.0-log
-- Versione PHP: 5.3.8

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `Sql0000_0`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `recipe`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recipe` (
  `phase` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  `start_hour` time NOT NULL,
  `end_hour` time NOT NULL,
  `color_0` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color_3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color_4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color_5` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color_6` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color_7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `temperature` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `humidity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `photowhite` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity_solution` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity_cicles` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity_duration` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dump dei dati per la tabella `recipe`
--

INSERT INTO `MEG_recipe` (`phase`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `start_hour`, `end_hour`, `color_0`, `color_1`, `color_2`, `color_3`, `color_4`, `color_5`, `color_6`, `color_7`, `temperature`, `humidity`, `photowhite`, `quantity_solution`, `quantity_cicles`, `quantity_duration`) VALUES
('germination_day', '2019-01-02', '2019-03-02', '08:00:00', '18:00:00', 100, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 54, 0, 1300, 24, 120),
('germination_night', '2019-01-02', '2019-03-02', '18:00:00', '08:00:00', 0, 96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 40, 0, 1300, 24, 120),
('flowering_day', '2019-03-02', '2019-06-02', '08:00:00', '06:00:00', 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 10, 25, 40, 0, 1300, 24, 120),
('flowering_night', '2019-03-02', '2019-06-02', '06:00:00', '08:00:00', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 120),
('vegetation_day ', '2019-06-02', '2019-09-02', '08:00:00', '06:00:00', 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 10, 25, 40, 0, 1300, 24, 120),
('vegetation_night', '2019-06-02', '2019-09-02', '06:00:00', '08:00:00', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1300, 24, 120),
('maturation_day', '2019-09-02', '2019-12-31', '08:00:00', '09:00:00', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1300, 24, 120),
('maturation_night', '2019-09-02', '2019-12-31', '09:00:00', '08:00:00', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1300, 24, 120);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```